# Url hide using codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter...  I want a clean URL from below URL

```
  http://localhost:8080/rtvnews/index.php/home/videonews?id=67598/newstitle
```

here home => controller, videonews => function and ?id=6586565 is a url string.

I want to  remove /index.php/home/videonews?id=67598 and replace with /news/

Below Final url I need to get

```
  http://localhost:8080/rtvnews/news/newstitle
```

Comment: What ever you did you have to pass the ID. But passing method can be changed

Comment: You should try reading the documentation where routing and URL formatting is clearly explained.  I also don't understand how you could have a URL with a query string when the CodeIgniter default is the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For hiding index.php from url use following htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

[More on htaccess](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file)

[URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=route)

**Considering newstitle as unique:**

> Go to your route.php file (application/config/routes.php) . Add new
>   route rule as below

```
$route['rtvnews/news/(:any)'] = 'home/videonews/$1';
```

> in your view file

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()."rtvnews/new/".$newstitle; ?>" > News Title</a>
```

> so your url became as below

```
http://localhost:8080/rtvnews/news/uniquenewstitle
```

> Your request go to home/vidonews function where you can get your
>   newstitle as parameter.
>
> In your controller.php function will be like

```
function vidonews($newsTitle){}
```

**Considering id as unique :**

> Add new route rule as below

```
$route['rtvnews/news/(:num)'] = 'home/videonews/$1';
```

> In view.php file

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()."rtvnews/new/".$newsId; ?>" > News Title</a>
```

> so your url became as below

```
http://localhost:8080/rtvnews/news/newsId
```

> Now your request go to home/vidonews function where you can get your
>   newsId as parameter. In your controller.php function will be like

```
function vidonews($newsId){}
```

Comment: Dear, thanks for your reply . I want to pass news id when click news title. but then url is  http://localhost:8080/rtvnews/index.php/home/videonews?id=67598/newstitle  . but i want to  http://localhost:8080/rtvnews/videonews/newstitle.

Comment: Is your issue still persist ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below

Step 1: .htaccess (the one which is at root folder)

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Step 2: routes.php
 add the code below

```
$route['rtvnews/news/newstitle'] = 'Your controller/method']; //Just a syntax to change the route in codeigniter. You can change the url as per you want.
```