# How to remove index.php at the end of URL in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. Now I want to remove index.php from URL

Example:

- **www.domain.com/city/city-name/index.php**
- **www.tomatosale.com/search/search-field/index.php**

Actually I want to remove the "index.php" at end of the URL,

Now my config.php `$config['index'] = ''`;

Please anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828542/url-hide-using-codeigniter/38830126#38830126

Answer (score 0):

Add a htacess file in the root of your project

```
RewriteEngine on
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thank for your response, I had try this code, this working only www.domain.com/index.php, Now I want to www.domain.com/city/city-name/index.php

Comment: is it working when you remove the index.php from the url?

Comment: Actually I want to remove index.php at end of the URL. Again I will try this code, Let see it is work or not

Answer (score 0):

I have this in all of my CodeIgniter projects' root

Add a .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You may also need the `rewrite_module` module enabled in Apache

Comment: Where I go to enable this "rewrite_module" ?

Comment: Is this on your local machine on or a server?

Comment: You can use the command 'a2enmod rewrite' on terminal

Comment: now I am using godaddy server

Comment: It should be fine with godaddy - see https://uk.godaddy.com/help/how-do-i-use-mod-rewrite-899