# Setting Routing rules for different classes in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

My application URL `"localhost/crdlabs/PHP"` goes to `"localhost/crdlabs/home/display/PHP"` which is done using route.php. The rule is as follows.

```
$route['(:any)'] = "home/display/$1";
```

Now that I have another controller class called `displayarticles()`. The current URL for this class is  `"localhost/crdlabs/displayarticles/article/learning-coding"`. I understand that I cannot use the routing above for the new controller. How to set a routing rule for the current one to make the URL look like "`localhost/crdlabs/learning-coding`".

**Note : `learning-coding` part is dynamically set which means there are several different articles that should go to the same controller.**

Any help/advise please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828542/url-hide-using-codeigniter/38830126#38830126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current routing rule.

```
$route['(:any)'] = "home/display/$1";
```

Will routes anything appearing after `localhost/crdlabs/argument` to `localhost/crdlabs/home/display/argument`.So the route `localhost/crdlabs/learning-coding` will be redirected to `localhost/crdlabs/home/display/learning-coding`.So you can not use like this.

But I suggest you to show your articles

```
localhost/crdlabs/displayarticles/article/learning-coding
```

To

```
localhost/crdlabs/articles/learning-coding
```

using the following routing rule.

```
$route['articles/(:any)'] = "displayarticles/article/$1";
```

Will be best.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Hek! I already knew this method but I am looking for a way to do the way I did with the first controller. If there is no way to do what I want to do then I shall choose to go by yours. Please advise

Comment: i don;t think that you can achieve this.because `$route['(:any)']` always force routes to `home/display/$1`.

Comment: Yes, I am of the same opinion as you are. I wanted to achieve this keeping SEO in mind.