# Routing with codeigniter with customized URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller named home, which is my default controller too. 
This is my path

```
http://192.168.1.100/FMP/mobile/home/index/suzuki-violin-school--6/102271
```

Now i am trying to rewrite the url as

```
http://192.168.1.100/FMP/mobile/suzuki-violin-school--6/102271
```

Where i need to remove both controller name and function name.
So far i tried putting this in route.php

```
$route['(?!user|product).*'] = "mobile/home/index/";
```

But it takes all other methods in home controller and other controllers to the index function of home controller.
Any thoughts on how can i achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828542/url-hide-using-codeigniter/38830126#38830126
I will help you

Comment: yeah never explicitly call the index method

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code in end of your `routes.php` file

`$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'home/index/$1/$2';`

above route get two parameter and pass it into home page index function and your index function will be ass follow

`public function index($parms1,$parms2)`

Hope it will solve your problem. If not let me know. I'll happy to guide you through

Comment: Thanks Fairy Dancer.. With this code i am now getting 404. Also i have a concern that putting this code will make my all functions from any controller to end up at home/index/$1/$2

Comment: Yeah it is. You have to validate that data in index function in home controller. And you have to enter that route in bottom of the routes.php page. Otherwise it wont allow you to get access into other functions of controller

Comment: And you have to set route for other functions to make it work

Comment: It work for me. I used it as friendly url for the users. `localhost/app/username` this will get the user details directly. I set route for all the pages and **at bottom** I set `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/users/$1` in bottom of the route